# Unknow option for tkinter scale widget

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-scale

I am coding a GUI where you have to enter a number. I want to have a scale but it fits my purpose very well. The problem is a scale goes to 1e-9 precision. This is much to precise for me. I am using `ttk` extension for `tkinter`. I have tried a couple of things but I saw that there is a digits option for the scale which, when there is a `StringVar()`, leaves the number of digits but it doesn't work, it cannot recognise the option. I tried to look in the library but I couldn't find anything, it was too complicated.

Here is how my code is formed:

```
scaleValue = StringVar()
scale = ttk.Scale(content, orient=HORIZONTAL, from_=1, to=5, variable=scaleValue, length=150, digits=1)  # here digits ins't recongnised
scale.grid(column=x, row=y)

scaleValueLabel = ttk.Label(content, textvariable=scaleValue)
scaleValueLabel.grid(column=x', row=y')
```

Here is the documentation:

> An integer specifying how many significant digits should be retained when converting the value of the scale to a string.
>    [Official Documentation : http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/scale.htm](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/scale.htm)

Comment: The `digits` parameter is for `tk.Scale` but not `ttk.Scale`.

Comment: Could I then alternate between tk widgets and ttk widgets ? And is there another difference ?

Comment: There are styling and cosmetic differences between the two. Also some options are not available in one another - but it is still possible to use `ttk.Scale` if you like its look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`digits` is a parameter only available to `tk.Scale`. If you switch to using it, then your code will work:

```
scale = tk.Scale(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, from_=1, to=5, variable=scaleValue, length=150, digits=5)
```

But if you really want to use `ttk.Scale`, you can use a different approach. Instead of using a `textvariable` in your `Label`, you can trace the changes on your variable, process the value first, and then pass back to your `Label`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

scaleValue = tk.DoubleVar()
scale = ttk.Scale(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, from_=1, to=5, variable=scaleValue, length=150)  # here digits ins't recongnised
scale.grid(column=0, row=0)

scaleValueLabel = tk.Label(root, text="0")
scaleValueLabel.grid(column=0, row=1)

def set_digit(*args):
    scaleValueLabel.config(text="{0:.2f}".format(scaleValue.get()))

scaleValue.trace("w", set_digit)

root.mainloop()
```